# What is the answer of this problem solving question?

Tags: problem-solving, calculator

You need to order 4 plastic cups for each of the 800 runners. Plastic cups are sold in 2 different pack sizes and you must choose one type of pack only. A pack of 500 costs  £12.50 or a pack of 800 costs  £23.20

What is the least amount of money it will cost to  provide 4 cups to each runner?

Comment: Well, what's the question here? You need $3200$ cups, right? So either you buy $4$ packs of $800$ each, or you buy $7$ packs of $500$ each. Now, choose the cheaper option (the question would be more interesting if you were allowed to choose from both types).

Answer (score 1):

4 cups for each runner: $4 \cdot 800 = 3200$ cups in total. 
$3200 / 500 = 6.4$ ( so at least 7 packs of 500)

$3200 / 800 = 4$ ( so at least 4 packs of 800)

$$7 \cdot 12.50 = 87.5£$$

$$4 \cdot 23.20 = 92.8£$$